# how to spawn a java program to reduce the running time

Tags: java

I have a java program to read a input file (input.txt) and print the  content of that file (after that i need to do some more work there i.e ssh to a machine and check status,send email etc..). Since the input.txt file is having more lines it takes around 3hrs to complete the program.

So like to use spawn concept in java (like thread) or some other technique to spilt the process while reading the input file and do the other work (ssh,checkstatus,send mail) in the same time sothat the  program willl take hardly ten mintues to finish the program.

I am newbie to Java. Could you please guide me how to put that logic. I have pasted the code here which I have right now.

Example of input.txt file:

> #
>
> ```
>     ABC
> ```
>
> #
>
> bigboy           72.24.1       72.24.157.57
>   bejack           2.24.157.97   1.24.157.69
>   boni             2.24.147.96   9.24.159.86
>   irony            7.24.145.93   8.24.209.55
>
> #
>
> ```
>    xyz
> ```
>
> #
>
> alches            2.24.140.199  1.24.140.46

Java program:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class panic_email{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    try{
        System.out.println ("Starting of program...");

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String Name = "";
        String IP = "";

        CSLOOP: while ((FileLine = bfr.readLine()) != null)   {
        FileLine = FileLine.trim();
        if ( FileLine.startsWith("XYZ") ){
                System.out.println ("End of program");
                break;
        }
        if ( !FileLine.startsWith("#") && !FileLine.startsWith(" ") ){
          String splitLine[] = null;
          splitLine = FileLine.split("\\s+");
          if( splitLine.length >= 3){
          Name = splitLine[0];
          Ip = splitLine[2];
System.out.println("Name:" + Name + "IP" + Ip); 
//Here after this I am doing some kind of extra work like ssh,checkstate,send email. So while coming to this point I need to spawn the process i think. 
         }
         }

 }

}
```

Could you please guide me how to do this

Thanks,
Ricks

Answer (score 5):

Java has great support for multi-threading. Please read the [Concurrency Section from Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 2):

Don't extend Thread unless you intend to change the way Thread works. Implement Runnable instead. You may also want to look into thread pooling (see `Executors`).

Basically you should create a class that implements `Runnable` and does the time consuming work in its `run()` method. Try and make this class encapsulate all the work required in an individual task (ssh, checkstatus, send mail). Your program could read through the text file and create instances of this task class and submit them to a thread pool.

Beware that you may need to throttle your program depending on;
a) how much system resources you have
b) how much system resources each task requires
c) how many tasks you will have running

A simple way of throttling may be to use a thread pool of a fixed size.

Comment: Thanks qwerky. This solution also looks good for me. I will try it out.

Comment: How can i pass the name,ip to the run() method in consiserring my case here.

Comment: I am planning to read the input.txt file from the main() and pass the name,ip to the runnable method. i.e RunnableThread thread3 = new RunnableThread("thread3");
Eg. here how can i pass my name,ip to the thread3. Please let me knkow

Comment: I am talking about this  based on the below links example, http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial

Comment: You can't pass args to the `run()` method. Your `Runnable` class should encapsulate the task. How about having the name and IP as fields and writing a constructor on your class that accepts them? Also I'd recommend against having Thread in your class name unless you are extending Thread, which you are not.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to add multi treading support for your java application. The Tread class can help you with this. See http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial for an easy tutorial.

Comment: could you please let me  know how can i pass the name,ip to the run() method based on the example/tutorial you have linked?

Comment: has been a while since i worked with runnable interface, but i would say add some private vars to the class with getters and setters and use these vars in the run method.